# Finding derivative using product rule

Tags: calculus

When finding the derivative of:

$z=(1+t^2)6^t$

I am working it out to:

$$\frac{dz}{dy} = (1+t^2)(6^t)'+(1)'(t^2)'(6^t)$$
$$=(1+t^2)(ln(6))(6^t)+2t(6^t)$$
$$=6^t((1+t^2)(ln(6)))+2t(6^t)$$

I believe this to be the answer, but correct  me if I am wrong. My biggest concern is that I am seeing some sources on the internet saying you need to use the $log$ of the value not the $ln$ even though we have been using the $ln$ value in class.

Comment: In many places people use log=ln

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answer looks mostly right. Here are a few changes:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dz}{d\color{red}t} &= (1+t^2)(6^t)'+(\color{red}{1 + }t^2)'(6^t)\\
&=(1+t^2)(\ln(6))(6^t)+2t(6^t)\\
&=6^t(1+t^2)\ln(6)+2t(6^t)\\
&= 6^t[\ln(6) + 2t + \ln(6)t^2].
\end{align}
$$
(Doing the last step might not be necessary.)
Note that you are treating (1+t^2) as a factor, so with the product rule you would have to take the derivative of that factor. That is why you need $(1+t^2)'$.

About your concern about $\log$ and $\ln$. People will disagree on this, but I believe that it is more common to write $\ln$ when we have base $e: \log_e$ and $\log$ when we are talking about base $10$: $\log_{10}$. But granted, this will depend on your textbook/teacher.

Comment: I thought you could derive 1 and 6^t separately because it is a term. Granted there is no difference in answer,  but correct me if what I did is considered incorrect among mathematicians.

Comment: @BobDunakey: Note that $(1)' = 0$, so you would loose that whole last term if you kept it.

Comment: Ok Thanks I just got it. If I did what I previously did I would end up multiplying the right side by zero. Thus giving me the wrong answer correct?

Comment: @BobDunakey: That is correct.